# Advice on how to structure a custom plugin

Tags: customization, database

I am attempting to create a custom plugin and would like some advice/ideas on how best to store the data.

Expected Posts ~ 1,000
Expected Users ~ 10,000

Each user will need to have at least one value stored PER post.

Is the best way to do this by adding new columns to the user_meta table?

Just looking for some guidance on the most efficient method so I don't bloat my db unneccesarily.

Thanks.

Comment: It’s a little bit hard to guess what numbers (and how many of them) are you storing based on the description above - could you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: So are you just saying that each business will have a "total" number and a "current" number, and when anyone uses the button on their page, both of those should increase by 1 and be displayed? It sounds like you can just create a "business" CPT and use postmeta - but it depends on whether you'll ever want to query by those numbers. If so you should make a custom taxonomy for the numbers so that those queries will run faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number in the above example are not indicative of a need for a custom database table solution, the database will be fine with just using the `users` table for the users, `posts` table for the posts and `usermeta` table for the link between users and posts.

Its hard to offer a more definitive answer without knowing a little more about what the needs of the business /  plugin are to be.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Casey.

I was hoping to use the existing database, just not sure how and felt an inefficient way would cause poor performance.

The best way I can describe the functionality is a Loyalty Stamp Card per business.  Each post is a business.  Each logged-in user will be able to collect stamps for the businesses, so each user will have their own "total-stamps" for each business which will change each time they collect another stamp.

Comment: @shaun21k there shouldn't be any performance degradation, if you have a half-million entries in post-meta it might start making a difference depending on the host.

Using `postmeta` or `usermeta` to store a simple counter per `business` post shouldn't impact DB / PHP performance. It would be hard to store data from these transactions for reports etc however. 

EG if you need reports on who collected a stamp for which business when (eg User A collected 24 stamps for Business Z in the last 12 months)  that sort or data report would benefit from a custom DB table.

Comment: thanks, it is a good point about future reporting.  I may have to have a think about potential future uses of this data.  So if I was to use the usermeta table to store this, would I need to create an array of all postIDs as keys and "total-stamps" as the value of those keys?  This is all new to me so I want to know what I should go away and research if you don't mind.

Comment: @shaun21uk storing all in one entry would not be the most efficient use case, Id consider one entry for each user / business combination EG a key called `business_stamps_$business_post_id` then query that using the post ID or a wildcard on a custom query EG `SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE business_stamps% AND 'user_id' = $user_id`

You should of course use WPDB to build and sanitize the query before running it.

Comment: That's a strong suggestion, I never thought of using one meta_key per business but it makes sense.  One more question while we are at this: would I be able to add multiple values to that key?  At the moment I only envisage one value (total_stamps) but I may want to add others in the future.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @shaun2k if you store it as a JSON object you can add as many keys as you need.

Comment: The JSON part went way over my head @Ben Casey :) If I create the variable $business_post_id, can I then pass it into the key name as your example above? Like `add_user_meta($user_id, busines_stamp_$business_post_id, '$total_stamps')`  Will this also create the column in the db?

Comment: @shaun21uk try this: 'add_user_meta( $user_id, “business_stamp_$business_post_id”, $total_stamps );'